# PL/SQL unique column identification from two table

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql, xquery, xmltable

I am using Oracle 11G.
I have a PL/SQL procedure which is reading XML using xquery from XMLTYPE column in a table. The XML contains data of DEPARTMENT and its SECTIONS. DEPARTMENT has one to many relationship with SECTIONS i.e. a DEPARTMENT can have one or multiple SECTIONS and there may be instances where DEPARTMENT will not have any SECTIONS.

Structure of XML is such that `<DATA>` tag identifies a DEPARTMENT and set of its corresponding SECTIONS.

**XML**

```
<ROWSET> 
<DATA>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP1</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT1</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
 <SECTIONS>
  <SECTIONS_ID>6390135666643567</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection1</SECTIONS_NAME>
  </SECTIONS>
   <SECTIONS>
  <SECTIONS_ID>6390135666643567</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection2</SECTIONS_NAME>
  </SECTIONS>
 </DATA>
 <DATA>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP2</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT2</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
 <SECTIONS>
  <SECTIONS_ID>63902</SECTIONS_ID>
  <SECTIONS_NAME>mySection1</SECTIONS_NAME>
  </SECTIONS>
 </DATA>
<DATA>
 <DEPARTMENT>
  <DEPARTMENT_ID>DEP3</DEPARTMENT_ID>
  <DEPARTMENT_NAME>myDEPARTMENT3</DEPARTMENT_NAME>
 </DEPARTMENT>
</DATA>
</ROWSET>
```

Query which i am using is:-

```
  select d.department_id
       , d.department_name
       , s.sections_id
      , s.sections_name
   from xml_unit_download t
     , xmltable(
         '/ROWSET/DATA'
         passing t.xml_file
         columns
           DEPARTMENT_ID   varchar2(20) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_ID'
         , DEPARTMENT_NAME varchar2(30) path 'DEPARTMENT/DEPARTMENT_NAME'
         , SECTIONS        xmltype      path 'SECTIONS'
       ) d
     , xmltable(
         '/SECTIONS'
         passing d.sections
         columns
           SECTIONS_ID     varchar2(20) path 'SECTIONS_ID'
        , SECTIONS_NAME   varchar2(30) path 'SECTIONS_NAME'
      ) s
 where
  t.Status = 7
```

Now this Xquery does not fetch the result of DEP3, how will i cater this?

-------------**UPDATED**-------------
**Expected Output**

```
DEPARTMENT_ID        DEPARTMENT_NAME                SECTIONS_ID          SECTIONS_NAME
-------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------- 
DEP1                 myDEPARTMENT1                  6390135666643567     mySection1
DEP1                 myDEPARTMENT1                  6390135666643567     mySection2
DEP2                 myDEPARTMENT2                  63902                mySection1
DEP3                 myDEPARTMENT3
```

Comment: Can you please show what your expected output should be?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Please see updated expected output, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make them outer joins:

```
...
   from xml_unit_download t
     , xmltable(
... 
       ) (+) d
     , xmltable(
...
      ) (+) s
...
```

which gives:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID        DEPARTMENT_NAME                SECTIONS_ID          SECTIONS_NAME
-------------------- ------------------------------ -------------------- ------------------------------
DEP1                 myDEPARTMENT1                  6390135666643567     mySection1
DEP1                 myDEPARTMENT1                  6390135666643567     mySection2
DEP2                 myDEPARTMENT2                  63902                mySection1
DEP3                 myDEPARTMENT3
```